# Xcode archives slow

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Recently I created a new project in Xcode, it went very slow when archived. It took more than one hour to finish the procession, it's far longer than other APPs I ever made, and this new APP is smaller than others, it runs fast well on simulator and iPhone, it takes about 70mb memory on simulator and 20mb on iPhone.

[image]

Xcode 8.0, swift 3.0

Any help?

Thanks.

---

*** edited at 10am 2017.3.2 ***

I archived twice today. The first took about 15 mins, and the second took more than one hour. :-(

I think it's a problem of deleted files in the second try. Some features of the APP are not fully developed, so I deleted some files and viewControllers in storyBoard before archiving. I just want to release them in next version.

Did the deleted files and viewControllers have some kind of connections with each other? and I need to clean them before archiving?

---

*** edited at 9pm 2017.3.2 ***

It's a weird problem! I have tried to archive for times. Deleted the DerivedData and restarted the computer

1. Deleted the temporarily useless viewController but kept its corresponding swift file, it took about 15 mins.
2. Deleted both viewController and its corresponding swift file, it took more than one hour.

When the viewController was deleted, the swift file was nothing related with, it's independent! So deleting the swift file did absolutely work, and building with no error proved this. It's an odd thing!

---

*** edited at 11am 2017.3.3 ***

I may find the key. It's a problem of dictionary. Refer to [Go Home Swift Compiler, You’re Drunk](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/04/26/swift-long-compile-time)

There is a similar dictionary in my project. I decreased the dictionary to 2 items, Xcode finished archiving within 5 mins.

Still, I don't know why deleting the swift file can cause the archiving slow and keeping it can run faster. After all, the dictionary is not in it and even not related with it ;-(

Comment: Are you sure that it wasn't your pc that is going slow? did you try to archieve more than once? did you try to restart and re-arcieve again?

Comment: @hasan83 other APPs archive fast, so I don't think it's the pc problem.

Comment: You didnt answer all my questions

Comment: Impossible to tell without more information. How much RAM does your mac have? Were you running lots of other apps? How full is your hard drive? Did you check in Activity Monitor to see what is going on?

Comment: if you only tried one time. and you didnt try to restart your pc and re-archieve again. you can't assume there is a problem.

Comment: @hasan83 after the last archiving, I have made some changes in codes and have not made the next archive. I'll try later and tell you then. Thx.

Comment: @DuncanC the pc has 8G RAM and enough hard drive space. Yes, you did remind me to check the Activity Monitor. I'll take a look in the following archiving. Thx.

Comment: Is the hard drive solid state or magnetic? If magnetic, have you let it get full before? Magnetic drives get fragmented as they fill up, which reduces performance. If your drive has gotten badly fragmented that would impact performance, although over an hour is an **ABSURDLY** long time to archive a small project like yours.

Comment: @hasan83 I made another two tries. See detail in my edited post. Thx.

Comment: This seems more like a question for superuser or askdifferent than for stackoverflow. If your app is reasonably fast to compile-and-run there is no reason why it should take a long time to archive, because archiving is just building.

Comment: @matt if just build and run on iPhone or simulator, it takes only seconds. And if I don't delete those files, it takes about 15 mins in archiving. I think it's related with those deleted files' connection, it may search something lost.

Comment: Clear the derived  data and tried to close unwanted apps that running and takes Ram Memory then you will get much faster than before try and reply pls ...

Comment: try deleting derived data and restart your machine and try again as Spynet said

Comment: @hasan83 Sorry, it didn't work. pls see the detail in the question.

Comment: @Spynet Sorry, it didn't work.